# Atari 1040STFM PSU Hissing, high pitch sound when on

Tags: hardware, atari-st

I have an Atari, which is working correctly, but the power supply makes this hissing noise as soon as it is turned on. What may cause it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is possibly a capacitor failing.

I had, possibly, a similar noise in an amp and after some time there was a "pop" and the cap exploded all over the inside...

Check it or get it checked.